# .Net Core Docker Unable to load DLL 'activeds.dll'

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have an ASP.Net Core application that runs fine on IISExpress.

I am completely new to Docker, so when I add Docker support to the project and run it chokes on this section:

```
DirectoryEntry processEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://MyLdap", user, password);
processEntry.Options.Referral = ReferralChasingOption.Subordinate;
DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(processEntry);
```

With the error:

```
DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'activeds.dll' or one of its dependencies: The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
```

I figure this is because Docker can't see the dll so I added the following to the Dockerfile:

```
COPY ["C:/Windows/System32/activeds.dll","activeds.dll"]
```

But this did not seem to improve things,  How do I make the dll available to the Docker Container?

Comment: That error says that the DLL wasn't found in your application's folder or the GAC. .NET doesn't look in System32, it looks in the application's folder or the GAC. Since you use docker, you should put that assembly in the same folder as the application

Comment: The entire [DirectoryServices namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher?view=netframework-4.7.2&viewFallbackFrom=netcore-3.0) is available only in the Full Framework. How did you add it to your application? Did you use the [Windows Compatiblity Pack](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/blob/master/docs/core/porting/windows-compat-pack.md) ?

Comment: @Lobsterpants Are you using Windows containers or Linux Containers? .NET Framework support only available in Windows Docker containers.

Comment: @anuraj yes I am using Windows containers